# Is there an equivalent to "user_likes" for comments for Posts within a News Feed using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have not been able to find any information that indicates that there is a similar way to get the information for whether or not the user associated with the access_token that is making a request to .../me/home?… to get News Feed posts likes each post in the return from the FB Graph API call. For comments there is a "user_likes" field that can be retrieved for a comment within a post, but I cannot (without error/failure) request "user_likes" in the comma delimited list of fields for the feed as in ".../me/home?fields=user_likes,…

From what I can see, the only way I can determine if the user likes each post is to compare the user's Facebook ID to the id of each of the likes for post. This is problematic in that many of the posts returned in the Graph API request return a subset of the likes with paging likes to get additional likes.

Has anyone found a way to solve this problem? I do not want to use FQL, and am aware that similar posts to this have received FQL solutions in response.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: I filed a feature request at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1468637860040091/

Comment: Thank you! The feature request you made would be of great value as an enhancement to the Graph API.

Comment: Unfortunately they mark it as Invalid bug. But you can try to file the feature request here, https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/139819329438825